# Using global variables as variable parameter on function on python

Tags: python, tkinter, project, func, global

Im trying to do a function (Inside another function wich is a Toplevel() window on tkinter) That takes different args from different objects and move them acording to the args. Using global variables.

The thing is that for every object, I need different global variables and I dont know how to put the necessary globals for every single object.

Im trying to move images created with canvas.create_image() and I had already done that, but with an specific case.

Let me see if I can explain better:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import Threading

def CargarImagen(nombre): 
    ruta = os.path.join('Imagenes',nombre)
    imagen = PhotoImage(file=ruta)
    return imagen

Space= Tk()
Space.title("Invaders! Give Some Space!")
Space.geometry ("540x540")
Space.resizable (width=NO, height=NO)

CanvSpace= Canvas(Space, width=540, height= 540)
CanvSpace.config(cursor="dotbox")
CanvSpace.pack()

ImagenFondoInicio= CargarImagen('Pantalla Inicio.gif')
FondoCanvSpace= Label(CanvSpace,image=ImagenFondoInicio)
FondoCanvSpace.pack()

DxInvader0=1 #direction x #These are the globals I need to switch on every case
DyInvader0=0 #directtion y

DxInvader1=1
DyInvader1=0

def VentanaPlayy():
    Space.withdraw()
    VentanaPlay= Toplevel()
    VentanaPlay.title("Kill'em all!'")
    VentanaPlay.resizable(width=NO, height=NO)
    VentanaPlay.geometry("540x540")

    def MoverInvader(numInvader, Global1, Global2, Invader): #This is where I want to put the globals as variables
        global Global1, Global2 #So this would work
        x,y= CanvPlay.coords(Invader)
        if Global1+x<=Listaif1[numInvader]:
            Global1+=-0.5
            Global1= -Global1
            y+=20
        elif Global1+x>=Listaif2[numInvader]:
            Global1+=0.5
            Global1= -Global1
            y+=20
            print("Maximo Limite a la Derecha", CanvPlay.coords(Invader))
        elif y>= 500:
            print("Game Over")
        CanvPlay.coords(Invader, x+Global1, y+Global2)
        VentanaPlay.after(50,MoverInvader(numInvader, Global1, Global2, Invader))

    def ThreadMoverInvader(numeromover):
        b=Thread(target=numeromover, args=())
        b.start()

    CanvPlay= Canvas(VentanaPlay, width=540, height=540, bg="white")
    CanvPlay.config(cursor="dotbox")
    CanvPlay.place(x=-1,y=-1)

    ImagenNave= CargarImagen("Ship.gif")
    Nave= CanvPlay.create_image(260, 520, image=ImagenNave)

    ImagenHowTo= CargarImagen("HowTo.gif")
    HowTo= CanvPlay.create_image(260, 250, image=ImagenHowTo)

    ImagenNave0= CargarImagen("InvaderJuego.gif")
    Nave0= CanvPlay.create_image(21, 300, image=ImagenNave0)
    CanvPlay.after(0, ThreadMoverInvader(MoverInvader(0, DxInvader0, DyInvader0, Nave0))) #I call the function here

    ImagenNave1= CargarImagen("InvaderJuego.gif")
    Nave1= CanvPlay.create_image(51, 300, image=ImagenNave1)
    CanvPlay.after(0, ThreadMoverInvader(MoverInvader(1, DxInvader1, DyInvader1, Nave1))) #And here with their own globals and variables

    Listaif1=[20, 50] #these are the lists I'm using for every if on the function I need
    Listaif2=[490, 520]

    VentanaPlay.mainloop()
Space.mainloop()
```

So is there any way to do this?

basically what I need to do is this:

```
A=1
B=2

def getglobals(global1):
    global global1
```

and call it like :

```
getglobals(A)

getglobals(B)
```

Thank You!!

EDIT: I define VentanaPlayy() Because I use that function as a command on a button.

And btw, escuse my poor english skills... As you may notice in the code... My main languaje is spanish :)

Regards from Costa Rica :D

EDIT2: Forgot to put the error message:

```
def MoverInvader(numInvader, Global1, Global2, Invader):

SyntaxError: name 'Global1' is parameter and global
```

Comment: Try using class. I son't think you would be needing global variables. Also,avoid defining methods within methods.

Comment: Where is the code for `MoverInvader`? That error means that you pass an argument `Global1` *and* have `global Global1` in the function; how is it supposed to decide which to use? If possible, get rid of `global`; it's usually a bad sign.